# is there a way to add an event listener for a specific firewall?

Tags: symfony

I have several firewalls , such as admin, main,  I wanna add a event listener to the admin firewall ,not main,  because some checks can only be doing for admin firewall,  I know that we can do this like this post said [How to Create a custom Authentication Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)

This post is about authentication when a user logins, but my case is that a user has authenticated successfully,and some works need to be done for all actions behind the admin firewall, not for a certain action. so this event listener should be happened after user logined, and it is only happened for a certain firewall, such as admin.  any way to do this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own listener and add the following code:

```
$token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
$providerKey = $token->getProviderKey(); // secured_area / firewall name
```

The providerkey is the name of the firewall.
For more info: https://reformatcode.com/browse

Comment: I guess this is a new feature for latest symfony, what version is yours please?

Comment: Im using version v2.6.11

Answer (score 1):

I've came across similar issue as you did recently. As there is only one Symfony's internal FirewallListener, you'd have to filter the firewall name in your listener. Skip all but `admin` in your case.

Comment: do you have any code please?  I found this issue in github ,https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14435,  it is a way to get firewall name, I can get a firewall name now, but I also need to listen a event which should be dispatched when  a user is authenticated successfully, SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN  is  not useful for my case, I thought it would be dispatched  every time when a user is authenticated, but somehow this doesn't happen